# Compute values in vector with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, vector, scipy

I use NumPy.

I have defined a vector `x` with NumPy and other variables with numerical values.

I will return a vector `y` of same length as `x` but the values `y[i]` in this vector `y` need to be computed from different formulas depending on the corresponding `x[i]`.

Can I with NumPy do something smart or do I have to iterate through the vector `x` and for each element in `x` determine if `x[i]` is either greater than or less than a specific value and determine which formula to use for the specific element?

I guess I could do something like

```
y[x > a] = 2*x+7
y[x <= a] = 3*x+9
return y
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out `np.where` http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html.

```
y = np.where(x > a, 2 * x + 7, 3 * x + 9)
```